# Passing parameters to javascript button click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a small application in MVC4.  It has a grid and every row has two things.
1) ID
2) Button

When user click on a button I need to invoke a javascript function passing ID as an parameter.  How can I do this in MVC.  I can eaisly do thin in case of .  Please help

Below is my code.

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Asset>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>

        <th>
            Show
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td width="80">
            @item.Id
        </td>


        <td>
            <button class="btnView" onclick="myfunction(@item.someProperty)">Show</button>
        ///How can I pass @item.someProperty as an parameter to click handler?
        </td>              
    </tr>    
}
</table>


<div id="imageDisplay">

    <p>

    </p>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#imageDisplay').dialog({
                autoOpen: false
            });

            $('.btnView').click(function () {
                alert('ok');
                //How can I get id as an parameter to this function?
            });            

        });

    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly just remove `onclick` handler from the button(You don't need it as you are handling `click` event with jquery)

Try this :

HTML :-

```
<td>
  <button class="btnView" data-prop="@item.someProperty">Show</button>
</td>
```

JQUERY :-

```
$('.btnView').click(function () {
     var prop = $(this).attr('data-prop');
     alert(prop);
});
```

OR

```
 $('.btnView').click(function () {
     var prop = $(this).data('prop');
     alert(prop);
});
```

OR(if you don't want to add `data-prop` on button then you can follow below answer,Just catch `'Id'` which is there in `td` of your `table`)

```
$('.btnView').click(function () {
     var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();
     alert(id);
});
```

Comment: I'd go with .data('prop') instead of .attr('data-prop') though both should work

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick` handler from the button (you don't have a function called `myfunction`)

Since you already have the `ID` value in the previous column, you can get it using

```
$('.btnView').click(function () {
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').children('td').eq(0).text();
});
```